# Proxmox 5.2 in OVH - second IP of the LXC containter not working

Tags: proxmox

I have Proxmox 5.2 server in OVH. I have few LXC containers and everything work just fine except when I add a second IP to the container it doesn't work - inside in the container the interface exists and I can ping it from inside. On the other hand from outside it's unreachable.
I checked few of the IP's and everyone of them work perfectly well if alone in the container.
The MAC addresses are OVH type.

Ah, and it was working in Proxmox 4.2 before I upgraded it to Proxmox 5...
Of course I was trying this with old containers and also with freshly made ones - no difference.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Provide more information on the network information, address classes and masks, routing, interface(s) of the host bound to the interface(s) of the container(s) . Clarify also what does mean "outside", is it the host, other container(s) or anywhere on Internet.

Comment: Confirm that you use bridging also

Comment: Sometimes it's handy to be able to reproduce the setup with a mock-up, if it's possible at all of course. Keep this in mind for informations to provide.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a whole lot of information, however going of past mistakes people commonly make it's likely that you have a singular interface and two IPV4s with different MAC addresses on each.

The correct setup is to ensure the interface hardware address (MAC Address) is the same as the one set on both IP's.

(within the OVH Control Panel)

1. Delete the 'Virtual Mac Address' from one of your IPs
2. Once removed, click 'Add Virtual Mac Address'
3. Select 'pre-existing' then choose the MAC of the other IP.
4. Ensure that the MAC address is the same as the one on the LXC Container.